# Calculate the individual user time on my site?

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

Need to calculate the average time a user spends on my site. Below is how we store each session against each unique uid.

Session status 1 means that the session is complete..and if it is 0 then the session is still active/user didn't logout.

Any suggestions on what approach to use?

Usersession

```
rowid   uid     session     createddatetime     SessionStatus   LastModifieddatetime    LastAccesseddatetime
226636  22      D958DFC3    02-03-2018 11:41:56     1           02-03-2018 11:43:07     02-03-2018 11:41:56
226635  22      67AABA7B    02-03-2018 11:40:16     1           02-03-2018 11:40:55     02-03-2018 11:40:16
218830  5048    1E1D7790    26-02-2018 07:04:29     1           26-02-2018 07:04:53     26-02-2018 07:04:29
218829  5048    0EB86803    26-02-2018 07:02:54     0                    NULL           26-02-2018 07:02:54
```

Comment: And how do you define the session time?

Comment: If I got it correctly, you update LastModifedDateTime once session is over ... if so just do `DateDiff seconds from CreatedDateTime and LastModifiedDateTime` and do sum of it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff --session time would be LastModifieddatetime - createddatetime..

Comment: @Veljko89 Yup, that's right..I did try doing it SELECT ISNULL(CAST(ROUND(AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL, DATEDIFF(HH, us.createddatetime, us.lastmodifieddatetime))), 0) AS INT), 0)
                           FROM UserSession us
                           WHERE us.uid = u.id (join on main user table)  but didn

Comment: It's giving me time as 0 and I need to have time in minutes..

Comment: @GordonLinoff Would you be kind enough to help me out? I have hit a roadblock, there is a user that seems to never log out but has logged in more than 200 times..in his case there are multiple sessions on the same day and with only createdondatetime

Comment: @Sanjay, the situation you're describing with the user who never logs off falls outside the scope of the question you have posted. You can't calculate an average time on a user that you don't have an end time for, which means you have a different question now. Once you know what you want to know about this other situation, if you need assistance, start a new question.

Comment: @EricBrandt You're right, this question stands resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correctly, LastModifiedDate is the "logout" status, so:

```
SELECT UserID, AVG(Datediff("minute", LastAccessDateTime, LastModifiedDate))
FROM table    
WHERE SessionStatus = 1    
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Thanks, GG.. What do you think about this  SELECT ISNULL(AVG(Datediff(minute, , LastAccessDateTime, LastModifiedDate)),0)  ?

Comment: Oh yeah, you wanted Average... Seems ok, but why do you need ISNULL? You should not get null from LastModifDate if you set SessionStatus to 1, I think...

Comment: Need that because there are some users that have never logged in so trying to show their time as 0

Comment: Seems legit. Please mark my answer as valid after :)

Comment: I have hit a roadblock, there is a user that seems to never log out but has logged in more than 200 times..in his case there are multiple sessions on the same day and with only createdondatetime

Comment: You can remove SessionStatus = 1 and ISNULL check and set it like this: AVG(Datediff("minute", LastAccessDateTime, ISNULL(LastModifiedDate, getDate())))